# python, scikit-learn - Weird behaviour using LabelShuffleSplit

Tags: python, arrays, random, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Following the [scikit-learn documentation for LabelShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#label-shuffle-split), I wish to randomise my train/validation batches to ensure I'm training on all possible data (e.g. for an ensemble).

According to the doc, I should see something like (indeed, notice that train/validation sets **are evenly split** via `test_size=0.5`):

```
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import LabelShuffleSplit

>>> labels = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
>>> slo = LabelShuffleSplit(labels, n_iter=4, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
>>> for train, test in slo:
>>>     print("%s %s" % (train, test))
...
[0 1 2 3] [4 5 6 7]
[2 3 6 7] [0 1 4 5]
[2 3 4 5] [0 1 6 7]
[4 5 6 7] [0 1 2 3]
```

But then I tried using `labels  = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` which returned:

```
... 
[] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[] [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

**(i.e not evenly split - all data has simply been put into the validation set?)** I understand in this case that is doesn't really matter which indices are put into the train/validation sets, but I was hoping it would still be a 50%:50% split???

Comment: are you sure that you're not just looking for `cross_validation.train_test_split`? the label shuffle split works by randomly selecting 50% of the the labels  ... but if there is only one label (in your case 0), how is it going to use the labels to do a 50-50 split?

Comment: @maxymoo That should work in this case (all 0), but my labels will not necessarily be like this, and the LabelShuffleSplit would be better to randomise the splits. I was hoping it would handle all possible cases like all 0 (could this be a bug?), although I suppose I could add some logic to  determine which version of split to use.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's like quantiles, you can't make a split if all the values are the same. why do you want label shuffling rather than simple train-test split? are you trying to do a time-based split?

Comment: @maxymoo I only have a small set of training data, and so hope to utilise as much of it as I can; i.e. instead of removing some as a validation (to check if I overfit) that is never trained on, I essentially want to create an ensemble which contains models that have trained on every bit of data available. Thanks for you help.

Comment: no worries, you should be using k-fold cross validation then, take a look http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html the idea is you use several splits of your data to estimate the model's performance, then you retrain the model on the whole dataset. don't use label shuffling unless you are trying to do time-separated splits or something like that.

Comment: @maxymoo - Fantastic! That's exactly what I need! Thanks sooooooooooo much!!!!